# Simplify $-2\sin(x)\cos(x)-2\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Simplify $-2\sin(x)\cos(x)-2\cos(x)$

The above expression is the derivative of a function, and part of a larger problem. I am wanting to simplify this to the form $-2(\sin(x)+1)\cos(x)$. I'm having trouble figuring out how to simplify this, even though I know where I am supposed to end up. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Factor out $-2\cos(x)$ and you get the desired result.

Comment: If it is for a derivative of a function ,I prefer to rewrite it as $−2sin(x)cos(x)−2cos(x) =\\-sin(2x)-2cos(x)$

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks to you both!

Comment: There's something fishy here. Somebody is learning calculus, but they can't simplify $-2\sin(x)\cos(x)-2\cos(x)$ to $-2(\sin(x)+1)\cos(x)$? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: It was simply dumb oversight on my part... Sorry! @TonyK

Comment: hint: 3 tens plus 7 tens equals how many tens?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You have a common factor of $-2\cos(x)$ in both terms.